# How to update a series of columns starting at the next blank column group in T-SQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to work out the best way of updating a group of columns in a single table, starting at the next blank group.

A simplified table structure for this case would be:

```
+--------+-----------------+----------+-----------+----------+-----------+----------+-----------+
| itemID | itemDescription | prodID01 | prodQty01 | prodID02 | prodQty02 | prodID03 | prodQty03 |
+--------+-----------------+----------+-----------+----------+-----------+----------+-----------+
|      1 | Item 1          | ABC123   |         1 | DEF456   |         2 |          |           |
|      2 | Item 2          | GHI789   |         3 |          |           |          |           |
|      3 | Item 3          | DEF456   |         2 |          |           |          |           |
+--------+-----------------+----------+-----------+----------+-----------+----------+-----------+
```

What I then need to do is look for a specific `prodID` in another table and if it is found then add in new values to then end group of columns to populate the data.

So the second data table would be something like:

```
+--------+--------+--------+
| prodID | newID  | newQty |
+--------+--------+--------+
| DEF456 | XYZ012 |      3 |
+--------+--------+--------+
```

In this case where if finds a prodID of DEF456 this would then populate the main table in the last blank column available.

So in the example data Item 1 would have the newID and newQty values populated in set 03 and Item 3 would have the values populated in set 02.

I hope this makes sense, in the actual data table I am working with there are over 20 column groups so I am looking to see a way to find the last empty column group and populate data on the end when needed.

As a quick note on this if it helps the prodID**XX** value will always be populated if there is data for that column group.

Thanks.

Comment: Do this with an UPDATE and a CASE statement for each of the Prod columns.

Comment: On the first sight this is an issue of design... Shouldn't it be a 1:n relation?

Comment: As Shnugo suggests, this looks rather odd. Do you have a plan for writing queries against a table like that? It looks like it will be a nightmare. Hopefully no one ever wants to update or delete a product for an item.

Comment: The issue is that it is a data table sent to me in this format as it is used in another system else where. Ideally I would have used a separate table for the products and linked to the item ID but it is not practical in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE TABLE [Table1] A
```

The first column will be the simplest:

```
SET prodID01 = (CASE WHEN prodID01 IS NOT NULL THEN prodID01 ELSE 
(SELECT newID FROM [Table2] WHERE [Table2].prodID = [Table1].prodID01))

SET prodQty1 = (CASE WHEN prodID01 IS NOT NULL THEN prodQty1 ELSE
(SELECT newQty FROM [Table2] WHERE [Table2].prodID = [Table1].prodID01))
```

from there you will have a lot of nested statements:

```
SET prodID02 = (CASE WHEN prodID02 IS NOT NULL THEN prodID02 ELSE 
(CASE WHEN prodID01 IS NOT NULL THEN
(SELECT newID FROM [Table2] WHERE [Table2].prodID = [Table1].prodID02))

SET prodQty02 = (CASE WHEN prodID02 IS NOT NULL THEN prodQty02 ELSE 
(CASE WHEN prodID01 IS NOT NULL THEN
(SELECT newQty FROM [Table2] WHERE [Table2].prodID = [Table1].prodID02))

SET prodID03 = (CASE WHEN prodID03 IS NOT NULL THEN prodID03 ELSE 
(CASE WHEN prodID01 IS NOT NULL THEN
(CASE WHEN prodID02 IS NOT NULL THEN
(SELECT newID FROM [Table2] WHERE [Table2].prodID = [Table1].prodID03)))

SET prodQty03 = (CASE WHEN prodID03 IS NOT NULL THEN prodQty03 ELSE 
(CASE WHEN prodID01 IS NOT NULL THEN
(CASE WHEN prodID02 IS NOT NULL THEN
(SELECT newQty FROM [Table2] WHERE [Table2].prodID = [Table1].prodID03)))
```

etc.

If you have over 20 columns, like you stated, this is going to be a long query, so I would agree with @Shnugo that this might be a design issue.

Comment: That makes sense, so it is just a matter of adding each subsequent column lookup on each iteration. Fortunately this will be part of a stored procedure that is run as part of an automated maintenance schedule weekly.